# Problema al definir un backend.py django

Tags: python, django

Estoy extendiendo la funcionalidad de usuarios de Django y he creado mi propio backend como sigue:

**backends.py**

```
from home.models import Usuario

class UserAuthentificacionBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = Usuario.objects.get(email=username)
            # en este punto, debes verificar la contraseña, yo lo hare como lo hace el modelo de usuario de django, siguiendo los metodos que trae este
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Usuario.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return Usuario.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except:
            return None
```

La clase de mi modelo que utiliza el backend. **views.py**

```
elif 'logInButton' in request.POST:
                if login_email and login_password:
                    try:
                        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['login_email'], password=request.POST['login_password'])
                        if user is not None and (user.activated):
```

mi fichero **setting.py**:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('home.UserAuthentificacionBackend',)
```

**home** es una app que creé.

El error que me lanza:

> local variable 'user' referenced before assignment
>
> During handling of the above exception (name 'authenticate' is not
>   defined), another exception occurred:

Sin embargo puedo crear correctamente usuarios utilizando el backend.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el problema venía del except.

yo tenía:

```
elif 'logInButton' in request.POST:
                if login_email and login_password:
                    try:
                        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['login_email'], password=request.POST['login_password'])
                        if user is not None and (user.activated):
                    except user.DoesNotExist:
```

y claro, user no está definida.